# Adjusting size PnP Adaptive Card Result

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, adaptive-cards

I have an Adaptive card customer Search on PnP Search Result page.
across each document I have an image thumbnail and when I click on the thumbnail and small screen opens and you can see they document. Is there a way to make that screen size bigger using adaptive card code? So I can view the document better?